# PHP : how to clean user input leaving UTF-8 (Russian, Turkish, English)?

Tags: php, regex, user-input, sanitization

Clean user submitted inputs of accidental or intentional junk.. I wrote the following to do this, and would be interested to see more efficient or better solutions to the same problem.
*Note: I use **mysqli prepared statements** after these on the mysql side of things.*

**First Case :**  user should be able to input UTF-8 (*only Russian, Turkish, English is necessary*) characters, and '_', *(this is for cleaning 'username' input by the user)*.

inputs :

```
$lang1 = " \  $:;/<ŞĞğş43\24234şğ_Ğüğsdç<a> #$#@!@^%*&^( <b></b>";
$lang2 = "еукд $ :;363 леВАЛДЖЫу-_жлаывф<em>вфы34234</em>вфывф#@!@^%*&^(&*)(()&^@#!~";
$lang3 = "dasda$RWERs636  da<b>asd_45646asd<em>";
```

To clean these I wrote this simple function

```
function clean($s = '')
{
  $c = mb_strtolower((trim($s)), 'UTF-8');
  $c = preg_replace ( '/[^0-9\p{Cyrillic}\p{Ll}\w]/u', '', $c); 
  $c = htmlentities(strip_tags($c), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  return $c;
}
```

which returns what I need;

```
şğğş4334şğ_ğüğsdçabb
еукд363левалджыу_жлаывфemвфы34234emвфывф
dasdadabasd_45646asdem
```

**Second Case:** only English characters are allowed, invalid chars and other UTF-8 chars should be removed. ( this is for cleaning 'email' input by the user )

inputs:

```
$email1 = "dasda @:;/<ŞĞğ  ВАЛДЖЫуda<b>asd_45646asd<em>.com";
$email2 = "^%(#*$#)$&(237469879şşşdsasadsdasd/||\><? ВАЛДЖЫуda<b>asd_45646asd<em> .com";
$email3 = "t est i @coЬm.tr";
$email4 = "&/(/&^+'!+!^+<em>test@com.kz()(  РЛОкуц <em> ";
$email5 = "++ ?ЕНГКУ   teЛОДКУst@mail.уцкru...";
$email6 = " ?ЕНГКУ   teЛОДКУst@.уцкua";
$email7 = " ++ fake.some--one+tag@gmail.com++";
```

As this part is for emails, and should only accept english characters, I wrote the following functions to clean and validate;

```
function clean_email($s = '')
{
  $c = mb_strtolower((trim($s)), 'UTF-8');
  $c = filter_var(strip_tags($c), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  $c = preg_replace ('/(?i)[^a-z\.@_\-\+\d]|[.@]{2,}/u', '', $c);
  $c = preg_replace ( '/^[+.-@]{1,}|[+.-@]{1,}$/u', '', $c);
  return $c;
}       

function valid ($v = '') 
{      
  if (filter_var($v, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == TRUE) {return 'valid';} else {return 'false';}
}
```

when called via :

```
echo clean_email($email1).' : '.valid(clean_email($email1)).'<br/>';
```

returns what I need

```
dasda : false
dsasadsdasd : false
testi@com.tr : valid
test@com.kz : valid
test@mail.ru : valid
testua : false
fake.some--one+tag@gmail.com : valid
```

p.s. 

- I don't need full UTF-8 / RFC compliance in this email input field, nor do I need to include all possible special characters that can be included in an email. I prefer being more restrictive and stated in the initial question what was needed along with what the function does. The idea here is more to get rid of mistyped characters than to validate the email,in an online site I'd rather not correct anything, and just throw an error.

- updated the regex in the clean email function to include + and - characters.

Answer (score 2):

https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/

> Don’t write your own security controls! Reinventing the wheel when it comes to developing security controls for every web application or web service leads to wasted time and massive security holes. The OWASP Enterprise Security API (ESAPI) Toolkits help software developers guard against security‐related design and implementation flaws.

```
$email1 = 'fake.someone+tag@gmail.com'; // this is perfectly valid email
echo clean_email($email1).' : '.valid(clean_email($email1));
// outputs: fake.someonetag@gmail.com : valid
// and you'll be emailing the wrong person.
```

Comment: Your email validation is bad. `fake.someone+tag@gmail.com` is perfectly valid. So what your doing is stripping out my plus sign and then validating it to say true. That's false positive. You can't alter someone's email and then validate it to true.

Comment: [RFC6530 amongst others](https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/eai/) defines UTF-8 usage in email. So in the long run it will be possible.

And I agree completely with Anthony.

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos - my mistake, corrected it. In such a scenario the registrant simply wouldn't be able to confirm their email (via the message sent there) and so wouldn't be able to register..